# AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.24.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally

Tags: apache, docker

I've created a very simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
```

But when I start it, I get this error:

> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

So, I don't know how to solve it. Any idea?

Comment: I found this solution documented at https://serverfault.com/questions/1024606/configuring-a-php-web-service-container-at-build-time/1025053#1025053 gives me Access to _any_ **Configuration File** I need to configure.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I'd like to offer another (maybe more Docker-ish) way of solving the warning message. But first, it makes sense to understand *what* Apache is actually doing to figure out the domain name before just blindly setting `ServerName`. There is a good article at http://ratfactor.com/apache-fqdn.html which explains the process.

Once we can confirm that `getnameinfo` is what Apache uses to lookup the name and that it uses `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to determine where to go first for the lookup, we can figure out what to modify.

If we check out the `nsswitch.conf` inside the container we can see that it looks up hosts in the `/etc/hosts` file before external DNS:

```
# cat /etc/nsswitch.conf | grep hosts
hosts:          files dns
```

Knowing this, maybe we can influence the file at Docker runtime instead of adding it to our configuration files?

If we take a look at the Docker run reference documentation there is a section on the `/etc/hosts` file at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#managing-etchosts. It mentions:

> Your container will have lines in /etc/hosts which define the hostname of the container itself as well as localhost and a few other common things.

So, if we just set the container hostname, it will get added to `/etc/hosts` which will solve the Apache warning. Fortunately, this is very easy to do with the `--hostname` or `-h` option. If we set this to a fully qualified domain name, Docker will set it in our `/etc/hosts` file and Apache will pick it up.

It is pretty easy to try this out. Example with the warning (no hostname):

```
$ docker run --rm php:7.0-apache
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sun Sep 17 19:00:32.919074 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) PHP/7.0.23 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Sep 17 19:00:32.919122 2017] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

Now with the `-h` option set to a fully qualified domain name:

```
$ docker run --rm -h myapp.mydomain.com php:7.0-apache
[Sun Sep 17 19:01:27.968915 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) PHP/7.0.23 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Sep 17 19:01:27.968968 2017] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

Hope this helps answer the question and provide some learning about Apache and fully qualified domain names.

Answer (score 12):

This is not an error it is just a warning and you can safely ignore it. What it is saying is that `ServerName` is not set so it will assume machine IP as the same.

If you look at the default configs present inside `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, you will find `000-default.conf` and `default-ssl.conf`

```
root@d591ab6febff:/etc/apache2/sites-available# cat 000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

The ServerName directive is commented in the config

```
#ServerName www.example.com
```

So if you are worried about the warning you should change it to the value you want like below

```
ServerName www.tarunlalwani.com
ServerAlias tarunlalwani.com
```

You would need to create a config in your folder and then overwrite the files from default config using Dockerfile. Then the warning would be gone.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using docker do this: add ServerName localhost to apache2.conf from the Dockerfile and then restart the server

```
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

RUN service apache2 restart
```

this should get rid of the warning.

you can also do this from the terminal

```
echo "ServerName localhost" >> /usr/local/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and don't forget to restart your server

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

The error should be gone after the server restart.

Comment: How do you add this from the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 4):

**Problem:**
While running docker file giving below error:

> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

---

**Solution:**
goto `root`
goto `etc` file
then goto `apache2`
then nano `apache2.conf` file
and then below the line `# The directory where shm and other runtime files will be stored.` put a new line (Enter) and write:

```
ServerName localhost
```

Save the file and exit root and run the `docker run` command again, it will work.

---

Youtube video reference link for the same issue: [Watch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Ru96LS0M-Q)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid that warning, you can set the ServerName with you IP.

See this example: [`tagplus5/docker-php/7-apache/Dockerfile`](https://github.com/tagplus5/docker-php/blob/master/7-apache/Dockerfile#L10)

```
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends iproute2 apache2 php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 \
        php7.0-mysql php7.0-sqlite php7.0-bcmath php7.0-curl ca-certificates && \
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
echo "ServerName $(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{print $NF; exit}')" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf && \
```

(although iproute can work differently on a Mac: it depends on your host. See [iproute2mac issue 8](https://github.com/brona/iproute2mac/issues/8#issue-114481689))

Answer (score 1):

I use to add

```
sed -i -e 's/Listen 80/Listen 80\nServerName localhost/' /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

either to the Dockerfile or to the entrypoint file if used.